# Geo location in keeps calling in my angular application

Tags: angular, geolocation

**GEOLOCATION**
I am getting popup for allow/don't allow every time refreshing my web page in safari.

When i am removing geolocation code from web. It works fine.

do anyone have idea what's going on ? Any help will be appreciated.

**Code for getting current location in browser**

```
getLocationLatLang(): Promise<any> {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resp => {
          resolve({ lng: resp.coords.longitude, lat: resp.coords.latitude });
        },
          err => {
            //console(err);
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It will ask every time until you select one option as default. you should allow/deny for that particular address.

Comment: If I deny it. It still appears. @Mridul

Comment: goto settings -> site settings and select location. you can change option as per your choice. 'ask' is by default.